# Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' in react native

Tags: react-native, multipartform-data, multipart

I am new to react native. I have created a form to upload images to server. But when I try to upload images keep getting error like this  =>
[Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']
please help thanks. I want to send data in multipart format

here is my code

```
 const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
     // base64: true,
    });
    if (result.cancelled) {
      return;
    }
  
    let localUri = result.uri;
    let filename = localUri.split('/').pop();
  
    let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
    let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;
  
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', { uri: localUri, name: filename, type });
  
    console.log(formData)
    return await fetch('https//xyxtech/Android_API_CI/upload_multipart_data', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      // header: {
      //   'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
      // },
      headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'},
    })
    .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
  // .catch(err=>err)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    Alert.alert("File uploaded");
    // return response.json();
  });
  };
```

Comment: upload your image to `aws` and give `link` of the same to server side. It is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a React Native issue per se. Your server responds with non-JSON body which cannot be parsed here:

`.then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())`

This likely means that your HTTP request is incorrect. Why is it incorrect – sorry, can't help you, since I'm not familiar with the API you are trying to use.

Comment: ok when I remove that like then my alert is print but I am not getting any response. its says= there was a problem sending log message to your development enviroment

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))`

Comment: is it right way to send data in multipart format to server

Comment: and how do i know that its fully working, because some says its right code but in my server images not getting

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, like other contributors said, the problem is not with the frontend (React-Native code snippet), it's with the backend (API). I accept. The error also indicates the fetch call is working fine. So, you need to test your API to confirm it returns the correct output. Use postman or the browser. Assign variable photo a value and call https//xyxtech/Android_API_CI/upload_multipart_data. Otherwise all should be well.